# Unschedule and Reschedule Cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, scheduled-tasks

How would I delay the 'schedule' and then it unschedules. So that there is a delay in the schedule then it reschedules and changes the interval to a smaller increment?

This the code

```
- (void)onEnter
{
[super onEnter];

[self schedule:@selector(addMonster:) interval:1.0];
[self schedule:@selector(addBomb:) interval:4.0];
[self schedule:@selector(addLife:) interval:45.0];

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by delay the schedule? are you looking for a way to  add monsters at reducing time intervals?

Comment: Yes but at a certain time

Answer (score 0):

in your init

```
[self scheduleUpdate];
```

In the update call the different selectors when the time condition is met. In order to create the time condition we will need a few global variables.

```
ccTime addMonsterAfterDuration = 1;
ccTime addMonsterDurationDecrementValue = 0.1;
ccTime timeSpentSinceLastMonsterAdded = 0;
ccTime addMonsterMinDuration =0.2;

-(void) update:(ccTime)delta{

    timeSpentSinceLastMonsterAdded += delta;
    if(timeSpentSinceLastMonsterAdded == addMonsterAfterDuration){
         [self addMonster];
         timeSpentSinceLastMonsterAdded = 0;
         addMonsterAfterDuration -= addMonsterDurationDecrementValue;
         if(addMonsterAfterDuration < addMonsterMinDuration){
              addMonsterAfterDuration = addMonsterMinDuration;
         }
    }
}
```

The above example is only for addMonsters. I believe you can do the same for other objects in your game.